# Loop structure gives wrong result

Tags: android, string, compare

I am trying to compare items out of my DB to the value of an EditText (user input). The answer can have multiple answers, seperated by a ','. I first put them into a stringarray and then compare them to the answer. The LevenshteinDistance checks if the answer is more or les good (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance).

```
        userAnswer = etUserAnswer.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        String[] answers = qAnswer.split(",");

        for (String answer : answers) {
            if (answer.equals(userAnswer)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Answer Correct"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvMessage.setText("You smartass!");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Wrong"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                points = points - 4;
                String answerGood = answer.toLowerCase();

                LevenshteinDistance lDistance = new LevenshteinDistance();
                int comparisonCheck = lDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance(
                        userAnswer, answerGood);

                if (comparisonCheck == 1) {
                    tvMessage.setText("Almost there, but not quite yet!");

                } else if (comparisonCheck > 1) {
                    tvMessage.setText("Are you serious, totally wrong?!");
                }
            }

        }
```

Suppose I am having the answers for a question in the DB as follows: tree,test,radio

I am having **two problems**:

**1.** When I type "radi" it gives me 'Almost there...' which is good. It should also give me this if I enter "tes", but instead it gives me the 'Are you serious,...' line. I guess it keeps comparing to the last one.

**2.** Every time I type in something which is not correct, I get -12 instead of -4. I suppose this is due to the fact I am having three answers and it loops three times.. but I don't know how I can make it count only once..

Anyone can help me on the way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to know the word which gives the least Levenshtein distance, you could modify your loop to find smallest distance only;

```
userAnswer = etUserAnswer.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
String[] answers = qAnswer.split(",");
LevenshteinDistance lDistance = new LevenshteinDistance();
int minDistance = lDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance(
                    userAnswer, answers[0].toLowerCase());

for (int i = 1; i < answers.length; ++i) {
    minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, lDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance(
                    userAnswer, answers[i].toLowerCase()));
}

if (minDistance == 0) {
    // Correct answer...
} else {
    // Wrong answer...
    points -= 4;
    // etc etc...
}
```

Comment: That indeed seems like a better structure. I'll try this one out! One question: you first define minDistance, and afterwards you take the minimum of this number and a new instance of my Levenshtein class.. Why do you do this? Is the for loop not going to give an error if a question has only one answer ? (or are you therefore initializing it from the beginning? )